# Python django cant activate virtual enviroment

Tags: python, django

I can't activate virtual enviroment and get 'cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system'

[image]

I tried to write 'activate' and './activate' but both dont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this error:

Simply you can open powershell as admin and then execute below command:

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
```

You will be prompted to accept the change, type A(Yes to all), and press ENTER on your keyboard to allow the change.

Close the PowerShell admin window, and go back to the PowerShell Window where you got the error. Run the command below

```
venv\Scripts\activate
```

And now your error is solved.

Comment: I second this answer and it would resolve the issue. 
If the `venv\Scripts\activate` command does not work. Change into the directory and run the `activate.bat` which will work perfectly

Comment: @FabriceHafashimana This error happens because the venv\Scripts\activate command tries to run the Activate.ps1 in windows powershell

Comment: The command activate.bat was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\activate.bat". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.

Comment: if i use .\activate.bat no error but eniroment isn't activated

Comment: @Serrator I think it is solved, right?

Comment: no i don't get (venv) written before PS C:\Users........

Comment: Yes i tried it seems that it didnt change anything

Comment: Where you ran that command?

Comment: I opened powershell on my computer and wrote that set-executionpolicy remotesigned

Comment: You should open powershell as admin

Comment: PS C:\Users\MARSHAL\Desktop\studybud\env\Scripts> activate.bat
                                                                                                                        
          activate.bat : The term 'activate.bat' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spell
ing of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: activate : The term 'activate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of t
he name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: A everything works i just wrote  .\activate

Comment: Finally, your error solved great

Answer (score 0):

If you are using virtualenv.

```
venv bin/activate
```

I am condering **venv** is your envionment folder and you're on the folder containing your virtual environment.

PS: you can create virtual environment using following command

```
virtualenv venv -p python3
```